# Unmet Peer Dependency (WebPack)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Anybody knows why I am still having a missing dependency error, even though it clearly shows the correct version of webpack is already installed below??

**When I ran npm start :**

'''
There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

```js
 "webpack": "4.41.5"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:
```

**When I run npm ls webpack, it gives me :**

```js
Chelseas-MacBook-Pro:website-expo-2018-master ipchelsea$ npm ls webpack
uwbce@0.1.0 /Users/ipchelsea/Desktop/website-expo-2018-master
├─┬ react-loading-screen@0.0.17
│ └── webpack@2.7.0 
├─┬ react-scripts@3.4.0
│ └── webpack@4.41.5 
└── webpack@4.41.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed out the steps you took to get here. You did something, or missed something out in the steps you did to end up where you are now.

You should delete `node_modules`, then do `npm i`, and see if that correctly installs the packages.

Also, add the contents of your `package.json` file to the question. You need to have one in the root of this project.